# Understanding the basics of Return Types

Tags: c#

Why is a return type important?  I understand what it is, but why do I need to use it?  If I could use void and still get the same result, why would I explicitly tell the code and therefore the computer to return a specific type?

Is it so the computer doesn't get confused?  For example:

```
public class Son
{ 
 string chair = "Wood";
 int room = 1;
 public Son
 {
 }
 public void CleanHouse()
 {
   //Do some chores
 }
 public int CleanHouseAgain()
 {
  //Do some chores
  return room;
 }
}
static void Main()
{
  Son.CleanHouse(); //without a return type I don't know what you want
   //So I'll will just clean something and hope that is what you wanted clean.
   //Son ends up cleaning a chair.

  Son.CleanHouseAgain(); //I have a return type int which is called room. Got it!
}
```

I sure this is horrible code, but that's not the point here, I'm just trying to imagine what a return type does for a computer and why it's needed.  I wrote code that does a math calculation and got the same answer whether it was void or return type specific, so why do I need it?

Comment: You can't return a value from a function with a return type of `void`.

Comment: A return type is really only useful if you need to *return* some result to the calling code. If you never need a value returned, then you obviously don't need to return anything (`void`).

Comment: Because sometimes you need to process data for a result (variable or object) and you want to break up your code in an intelligent way.

Comment: That value from CleanHouseAgain is *not* called "room". The fact that it came from some variable with that name is not known to any calling code

Comment: Imagine a situation where cleaning a room could fail. In this case you could return a bool which is (true/false) from your CleanHouse function. Returning true if the room was cleaned succesfully and false if not. There are a lot more situations where datatypes are useful, but I think you need to study a bit more on your own here, still looks like you're fairly inexperienced. Good luck!

Comment: @Amy Ehhhh... There are ways to return values from a `void` function (i.e. `ref`/`out` parameters), but I think general consensus is that those methods not be used in that way (specifically `void` functions). But I agree with the intent of your comment.

Comment: Thanks everyone, sometimes you over think a very simple problem that you already understand.  In this case, long hours must have given me the idea that you could return a value when using void.  I went back to something I wrote and realized where I twisted my thinking and lead to a very "duh" moment for me.  I also realized I presented a horrible example of what I thought a return type did or was doing.

Comment: It would be good to update the title of the question since it's a little vague. Think of what search terms you would Google if you were hoping to find an answer to your specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method's return type isn't the best way to know what it does. We could have all sorts of methods that do different things but all have the same return types.

The return type also doesn't decide what the method does - that is, clean a room or clean a chair.

Let's look at this:

```
Son.CleanHouse(); //without a return type I don't know what you want
  //So I'll will just clean something and hope that is what you wanted clean.
  //Son ends up cleaning a chair.
```

There are two scenarios, both of which are valid.

One is that we want the son to clean a room, not a chair. In that case we should have two methods, `CleanRoom` and `CleanChair`. It's not the return type that tells us what the method does. It's really our knowledge of what we expect that class to do that tells us what the method does. If we didn't already know what we thought the method did then we wouldn't have any reason to call it. We wouldn't call it, get the return value, and then determine whether or not we should have called it.

How do we know what the method does? If it's our own method then we know what it does. If we can look at it then we can read it and see what it does. But neither one of those is ideal. The next person might not know our code like we do, and they might not want to read it all to figure out what it does. So one way to communicate what a method does is to *give it a good name that says what it does*. (And then make sure the method actually does that, not something else.)

---

Here's another valid scenario. Maybe we call `Son.CleanHouse()` and we actually don't want to know if he cleans a room or a chair. That can be a really good thing. It means that the logic to figure out what to clean and how to clean it is in the `Son` class. Code that calls `Son.CleanHouse()` doesn't need to know about that logic. That keeps parts of our application from getting mixed up together. One class knows how to do something. Another class tells it to what it does but doesn't know how the other class does it. That's good.

---

If you don't need a return value then don't return anything. If `Son` is going to `CleanHouse` and the calling code doesn't need to know exactly what got cleaned, then there's no point in a return value.

`CleanHouse` could return a `CleaningResults` object that details exactly what got cleaned, but if the calling code doesn't know about the details of cleaning then what would it do with that information anyway?

If the point is to make sure that a specific room gets cleaned then this would make more sense:

```
void CleanRoom(int roomId);
```

If we care which room gets cleaned then we tell it to clean that room.

This is not a rule by any means, but a suggestion: If a class can handle its responsibility without other classes telling it what to do or getting a detailed result about exactly what was done, that's good. It means that our classes are a little less coupled, a little less aware of what the others are doing. Sometimes they need to share more information, but it can be beneficial to limit how much they share if we can.

Answer (score 1):

A return value is generally used for 1 of several reasons.

- A value resulting from a query or computation ( e.g. fnAdd(a, b)
  returns a sum (float, int, etc..)
- The updated state (e.g. array.join() returns a new array with updated
  elements)
- A result of the action : success or failure (booleen, or a failure
  code)

Answer (score 0):

Because functions returns can be fed as input to other functions, and statically typed languages allow the programmer to make sure that the logic of his design stands by giving him the possibility to define all input and output types so he makes sure that they match each other.